# Flask - request.files become empty dictionary in before_request decorated function

Tags: flask, python-3.7

I am not sure if anyone has encountered this issue. My Flask behaves strangely when I run it. So, given the following code:

```py
@bb.before_request
def check_if_auth():
    # Deals with CORS ISSUE FOR Preflight Requests
    ## This needs to be the first line.
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        return make_response("OK", 200)
    
    if os.environ.get("ENV") == "development":
        # Cannot return response, just pass it so that the other handlers can deal with it
        # return make_response("Hello", 200)
        logger.info(request.endpoint)
        logger.debug(request.headers)
        pass
    else:
        func = app.view_functions[request.endpoint]
        if hasattr(func, '_exclude_from_check'):
            logger.info(f"{func} does not require auth check")
            pass
        else:
            path = "A"
            headers = {"Authorization": request.headers.get("Authorization")}
            res = requests.get(f"auth service URL here", params={"path":path}, headers=headers)
            # code cut for brevity
```

and the following path for file upload:

```py
@bb.route("/add", methods=['POST'])
def create():

    # cut for brevity

    if 'file' not in request.files:
        status['status'] = "error"
        status['message'] = "Missing File upload"
        return make_response(status, 400)
    # cut for brevity
```

I have encountered a strange occurrence where the request.files is an empty immutable dict even after making a POST multipart upload request to the `/add` endpoint resulting in the 400 response. However, if I were to add `logger.info(request.files)` right here:

```py
    
   else:
       logger.info(request.files)
       func = app.view_functions[request.endpoint]
```

The file upload works magically. I tried putting in other locations such as at the end of this decorated function `check_if_auth()`, the file upload fails. Does anyone have any insight as to why this happens?

A litte more information on the environment:

- It is kind of in a docker environment.
- I am running Waitress.